# Magento themes are developed responsive only related to width or to height also?

Tags: theme, rwd

I need information about Magento themes.

We are planning to buy a Magento theme.

Most of the themes are responsive by width only.

Are Magento themes developed responsive only related to width or also to height?

Comment: You know that the height doesn´t matter. Its only about the width basically. You can always scroll on a website or?

Comment: yes, you are right.... means, usually every theme will build with respect to width only.....

Comment: gave you a proper answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every theme is build to width only because the height is relative. You can always scroll the website on any device and therefore the major point of a responsive theme will be width related. Only exceptions are the graphics for the menu etc in the theme but that should be all good with the responsive desgins. 
The exceptions will be related to each theme individual